# How can I have my JQueryUI draggable elements float over into another overflowed element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I have two areas that will be scrollable on iPad, so I kept their overflow to auto (or scroll, or hidden which still allows scrolling on iPad).

I have a section of unenrolled students, and I'm using JQueryUI (with touchPunch for touch) to drag a student from a bin of unenrolled students into the class they belong in.

This works fine except for when I set overflow to allow scrolling. I think I need to pop the element out of its parent first, then start dragging. Then on drop, append that element to the droppable container.

Here's a JS bin of it in action:

http://jsbin.com/aPaHiVi/3/edit

`Contains 1 working and 1 not-working example`

The thing is, I'm not sure how to override the default draggable code, and have it:

1. Set to the same position I picked it up but as a child of its parent's parent
2. Have it set as a child of the dropped container in the correct position

Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Thanks for reading

Comment: Playing a bit with your code I was able to make a workaround, you can actually use the helper option and drag it with scroll without major problems like this `$('o').draggable({helper:'clone'});`, might not be the desirable effect in terms of design but works, check this out http://jsbin.com/OWeyebic/2/edit

Comment: Cant you just make the area oveflow:hidden when you start dragging?

Comment: The clone's a great idea! Then I could do the add / remove child after the user has made a decision. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add this to your css:

```
.nooverflow{overflow:visible;}
```

And this to the ready function:

```
$('o').draggable({
    start:function()
    {
        $(this).parent().addClass('nooverflow');              
    },
    stop:function()
    {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('nooverflow');            
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It's a good start. The start and stop function parameters are a big help in itself. I'll do some testing and accept if it works